# Stop the message _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)

Tags: c++

I get the message

```
_WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
```

from every cpp file.

I tried adding the following to the main file before any headers (got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871513/how-to-get-rid-of-win32-winnt-not-defined-warning)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x05010000 //I want to support XP
```

and I still get these messages for different cpp files. Any suggestions on how I could stop these messages from displaying I am using VS2012

Answer (score 1):

The constant you want to define is `_WIN32_WINNT` not `_WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER`.  The possible values are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx

You should define it before including `windows.h`.

Comment: I just updated the post. Do i need to do this in very cpp file ?

Comment: You need it before every #include of windows.h.  Usually that would be one place only: in stdafx.h

Comment: The value you are using isn't appropriate for that constant, you should use one from the table at the link I provided.  The value you're using would be if you decide to define `NTDDI_VERSION` which also requires that you define `_WIN32_WINNT`.  As @ScottMcP-MVP said, you need to define these before including `windows.h` anywhere you include it.  If you use a precompiled header than that's most likely the right spot.